# Core Location Extraction of Data then Uploading to Firebase

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

I am new to programming. I am trying to figure out how to get the coordinates from my locationManager function so that I can connect them to Firebase. I keep receiving error: type 'CLLocation!' has no member 'latitude'.

I am stuck trying to figure out how to get the myLocation variable coordinates outside of the locationManager function.

Any advice will help!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreLocation

class SignupViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {


     let manager = CLLocationManager()
     let currentUserLocation = CLLocation!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let cloud = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://applesandoranges.appspot.com")

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        userStorage = cloud.child("users")

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()



    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to declare a property for the current user location. Try this declaration instead:

```
var currentUserLocation: CLLocation? = nil
```

Then in your delegate function (location manager did update), you just set the property:

```
currentUserLocation = locations[0]
```

I think that answers your question of how to get the location value out of the function and into (a property of) your view controller.

Make sense?

PS -

I'm curious that Xcode did not report an error on your declaration:

```
let currentUserLocation = CLLocation!
```

My version of Xcode insists on having a member name or initializer after the class name. So I would have to type `CLLocation.self` for the class itself or `CLLocation(args)` to construct an instance. That was the source of your strange error message, i.e. confusing a type and an instance of that type.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up having to change the CLLocation to CLLocationCoordinate2D to have it work.